# How to determine the sequence of this graph?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-series

I can solve a Fourier series, but I don’t know how to determine the sequence. 
It is necessary to determine the values ​​of the imaginary part of the Fourier coefficients of the following sequence: Graph in Picture. [image: Click here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define this as a periodic function with period $T$: $$f(t)=\dfrac{1}{T}t\quad\text{where}\,\,kT\lt t\le (k+1)T\quad\text{for}\,\,k\in\mathbb Z$$ since when $t=0$, $f(0)=0$ and when $t=T$, $f(T)=1.$